# UserForm to fill a spreadsheet

Tags: vba, userform

I presently have a coding that will a person to complete a UserForm - select submit and the info is fed into a spreadsheet (same Workbook).

the problem I have is that the tombstone info such as First Name, Last Name, ID, Language and Email address. etc.... is completed once in the UserForm but the person can select a number of Provinces and Cities (up to 10 options)

```
John/ Smith/ 12568/ Bilingual/ John.Smith@gmail.com
New Brunswick/ Moncton
Quebec/ Montreal
Nova Scotia/ Halifax
```

I need the tombstone information to populate on each line for search purposes but if the person only selects on Province then I don't want it stop populating.

the present coding I have populates but automatically takes up 10 lines in the spreadsheet regardless if there is information if the cells

the coding is pretty long as this was the only way I knew how to do it

```
 With ws
       .Unprotect Password:="Transfer19"
       .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.TxtFirst.Value

      If Me.ListProv2.Value = "" Then
      .Cells(iRow + 1, 1).Value = ""
      Else
      .Cells(iRow + 1, 1).Value = Me.TxtFirst.Value
      End If

      If Me.ListProv3.Value = "" Then
      .Cells(iRow + 2, 1).Value = ""
      Else
      .Cells(iRow + 2, 1).Value = Me.TxtFirst.Value
      End If

      If Me.ListProv4.Value = "" Then
      .Cells(iRow + 3, 1).Value = ""
      Else
      .Cells(iRow + 3, 1).Value = Me.TxtFirst.Value
      End If

      If Me.ListProv5.Value = "" Then
      .Cells(iRow + 4, 1).Value = ""
      Else
      .Cells(iRow + 4, 1).Value = Me.TxtFirst.Value
      End If

      If Me.ListProv6.Value = "" Then
      .Cells(iRow + 5, 1).Value = ""
      Else
      .Cells(iRow + 5, 1).Value = Me.TxtFirst.Value
      End If

      If Me.ListProv7.Value = "" Then
      .Cells(iRow + 6, 1).Value = ""
      Else
      .Cells(iRow + 6, 1).Value = Me.TxtFirst.Value
      End If

      If Me.ListProv8.Value = "" Then
      .Cells(iRow + 7, 1).Value = ""
      Else
      .Cells(iRow + 7, 1).Value = Me.TxtFirst.Value
      End If

      If Me.ListProv9.Value = "" Then
      .Cells(iRow + 8, 1).Value = ""
      Else
      .Cells(iRow + 8, 1).Value = Me.TxtFirst.Value
      End If

      If Me.ListProv10.Value = "" Then
      .Cells(iRow + 9, 1).Value = ""
      Else
      .Cells(iRow + 9, 1).Value = Me.TxtFirst.Value
      End If


      .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.TxtLast.Value
      If Me.ListProv2.Value = "" Then
      .Cells(iRow + 1, 2).Value = ""
      Else
      .Cells(iRow + 1, 2).Value = Me.TxtLast.Value
      End If

      If Me.ListProv3.Value = "" Then
      .Cells(iRow + 2, 2).Value = ""
      Else
      .Cells(iRow + 2, 2).Value = Me.TxtLast.Value
      End If

      If Me.ListProv4.Value = "" Then
      .Cells(iRow + 3, 2).Value = ""
      Else
      .Cells(iRow + 3, 2).Value = Me.TxtLast.Value
      End If

      If Me.ListProv5.Value = "" Then
      .Cells(iRow + 4, 2).Value = ""
      Else
      .Cells(iRow + 4, 2).Value = Me.TxtLast.Value
      End If

      If Me.ListProv6.Value = "" Then
      .Cells(iRow + 5, 2).Value = ""
      Else
      .Cells(iRow + 5, 2).Value = Me.TxtLast.Value
      End If

      If Me.ListProv7.Value = "" Then
      .Cells(iRow + 6, 2).Value = ""
      Else
      .Cells(iRow + 6, 2).Value = Me.TxtLast.Value
      End If

 If Me.ListProv8.Value = "" Then
 .Cells(iRow + 7, 2).Value = ""
 Else
 .Cells(iRow + 7, 2).Value = Me.TxtLast.Value
 End If

 If Me.ListProv9.Value = "" Then
 .Cells(iRow + 8, 2).Value = ""
 Else
 .Cells(iRow + 8, 2).Value = Me.TxtLast.Value
 End If

 If Me.ListProv10.Value = "" Then
 .Cells(iRow + 9, 2).Value = ""
 Else
 .Cells(iRow + 9, 2).Value = Me.TxtLast.Value
 End If

 .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.TxtPRI.Value

 If Me.ListProv2.Value = "" Then
 .Cells(iRow + 1, 3).Value = ""
 Else
 .Cells(iRow + 1, 3).Value = Me.TxtPRI.Value
 End If

 If Me.ListProv3.Value = "" Then
 .Cells(iRow + 2, 3).Value = ""
 Else
 .Cells(iRow + 2, 3).Value = Me.TxtPRI.Value
 End If

 If Me.ListProv4.Value = "" Then
 .Cells(iRow + 3, 3).Value = ""
 Else
 .Cells(iRow + 3, 3).Value = Me.TxtPRI.Value
 End If

 If Me.ListProv5.Value = "" Then
 .Cells(iRow + 4, 3).Value = ""
 Else
 .Cells(iRow + 4, 3).Value = Me.TxtPRI.Value
 End If

 If Me.ListProv6.Value = "" Then
 .Cells(iRow + 5, 3).Value = ""
 Else
 .Cells(iRow + 5, 3).Value = Me.TxtPRI.Value
 End If

 If Me.ListProv7.Value = "" Then
 .Cells(iRow + 6, 3).Value = ""
 Else
 .Cells(iRow + 6, 3).Value = Me.TxtPRI.Value
 End If

 If Me.ListProv8.Value = "" Then
 .Cells(iRow + 7, 3).Value = ""
 Else
 .Cells(iRow + 7, 3).Value = Me.TxtPRI.Value
 End If

 If Me.ListProv9.Value = "" Then
 .Cells(iRow + 8, 3).Value = ""
 Else
 .Cells(iRow + 8, 3).Value = Me.TxtPRI.Value
 End If

 If Me.ListProv10.Value = "" Then
 .Cells(iRow + 9, 3).Value = ""
 Else
 .Cells(iRow + 9, 3).Value = Me.TxtPRI.Value
 End If

  'Copy Group
 .Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.TxtGR.Value
 If Me.ListProv2.Value = "" Then
 .Cells(iRow + 1, 4).Value = ""
 Else
 .Cells(iRow + 1, 4).Value = Me.TxtGR.Value
 End If

 If Me.ListProv3.Value = "" Then
 .Cells(iRow + 2, 4).Value = ""
 Else
 .Cells(iRow + 2, 4).Value = Me.TxtGR.Value
 End If

 If Me.ListProv4.Value = "" Then
 .Cells(iRow + 3, 4).Value = ""
 Else
 .Cells(iRow + 3, 4).Value = Me.TxtGR.Value
 End If

 If Me.ListProv5.Value = "" Then
 .Cells(iRow + 4, 4).Value = ""
 Else
 .Cells(iRow + 4, 4).Value = Me.TxtGR.Value
 End If

 If Me.ListProv6.Value = "" Then
 .Cells(iRow + 5, 4).Value = ""
 Else
 .Cells(iRow + 5, 4).Value = Me.TxtGR.Value
 End If

 If Me.ListProv7.Value = "" Then
 .Cells(iRow + 6, 4).Value = ""
 Else
 .Cells(iRow + 6, 4).Value = Me.TxtGR.Value
 End If

 If Me.ListProv8.Value = "" Then
 .Cells(iRow + 7, 4).Value = ""
 Else
 .Cells(iRow + 7, 4).Value = Me.TxtGR.Value
 End If

 If Me.ListProv9.Value = "" Then
 .Cells(iRow + 8, 4).Value = ""
 Else
 .Cells(iRow + 8, 4).Value = Me.TxtGR.Value
 End If

 If Me.ListProv10.Value = "" Then
 .Cells(iRow + 9, 4).Value = ""
 Else
 .Cells(iRow + 9, 4).Value = Me.TxtGR.Value
 End If

   ' copy Level
 .Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.TxtLV.Value
 If Me.ListProv2.Value = "" Then
 .Cells(iRow + 1, 5).Value = ""
 Else
 .Cells(iRow + 1, 5).Value = Me.TxtLV.Value
 End If

 If Me.ListProv3.Value = "" Then
 .Cells(iRow + 2, 5).Value = ""
 Else
 .Cells(iRow + 2, 5).Value = Me.TxtLV.Value
 End If

 If Me.ListProv4.Value = "" Then
 .Cells(iRow + 3, 5).Value = ""
 Else
   .Cells(iRow + 3, 5).Value = Me.TxtLV.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv5.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 4, 5).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 4, 5).Value = Me.TxtLV.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv6.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 5, 5).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 5, 5).Value = Me.TxtLV.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv7.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 6, 5).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 6, 5).Value = Me.TxtLV.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv8.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 7, 5).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 7, 5).Value = Me.TxtLV.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv9.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 8, 5).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 8, 5).Value = Me.TxtLV.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv10.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 9, 5).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 9, 5).Value = Me.TxtLV.Value
   End If

   ' Copy linguistic
   .Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.TxtLinguistic.Value
   If Me.ListProv2.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 1, 6).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 1, 6).Value = Me.TxtLinguistic.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv3.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 2, 6).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 2, 6).Value = Me.TxtLinguistic.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv4.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 3, 6).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 3, 6).Value = Me.TxtLinguistic.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv5.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 4, 6).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 4, 6).Value = Me.TxtLinguistic.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv6.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 5, 6).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 5, 6).Value = Me.TxtLinguistic.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv7.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 6, 6).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 6, 6).Value = Me.TxtLinguistic.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv8.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 7, 6).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 7, 6).Value = Me.TxtLinguistic.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv9.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 8, 6).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 8, 6).Value = Me.TxtLinguistic.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv10.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 9, 6).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 9, 6).Value = Me.TxtLinguistic.Value
   End If

   ' Copy Email
   .Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.TxtEmail.Value
   If Me.ListProv2.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 1, 7).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 1, 7).Value = Me.TxtEmail.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv3.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 2, 7).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 2, 7).Value = Me.TxtEmail.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv4.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 3, 7).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 3, 7).Value = Me.TxtEmail.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv5.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 4, 7).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 4, 7).Value = Me.TxtEmail.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv6.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 5, 7).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 5, 7).Value = Me.TxtEmail.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv7.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 6, 7).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 6, 7).Value = Me.TxtEmail.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv8.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 7, 7).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 7, 7).Value = Me.TxtEmail.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv9.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 8, 7).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 8, 7).Value = Me.TxtEmail.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv10.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 9, 7).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 9, 7).Value = Me.TxtEmail.Value
   End If

   ' Copy Resume Number
   .Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Me.TxtResumeNum.Value
   If Me.ListProv2.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 1, 8).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 1, 8).Value = Me.TxtResumeNum.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv3.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 2, 8).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 2, 8).Value = Me.TxtResumeNum.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv4.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 3, 8).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 3, 8).Value = Me.TxtResumeNum.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv5.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 4, 8).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 4, 8).Value = Me.TxtResumeNum.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv6.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 5, 8).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 5, 8).Value = Me.TxtResumeNum.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv7.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 6, 8).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 6, 8).Value = Me.TxtResumeNum.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv8.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 7, 8).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 7, 8).Value = Me.TxtResumeNum.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv9.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 8, 8).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 8, 8).Value = Me.TxtResumeNum.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv10.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 9, 8).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 9, 8).Value = Me.TxtResumeNum.Value
   End If

   ' Copy Reason
   .Cells(iRow, 9).Value = Me.TxtReason.Value
   If Me.ListProv2.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 1, 9).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 1, 9).Value = Me.TxtReason.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv3.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 2, 9).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 2, 9).Value = Me.TxtReason.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv4.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 3, 9).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 3, 9).Value = Me.TxtReason.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv5.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 4, 9).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 4, 9).Value = Me.TxtReason.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv6.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 5, 9).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 5, 9).Value = Me.TxtReason.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv7.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 6, 9).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 6, 9).Value = Me.TxtReason.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv8.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 7, 9).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 7, 9).Value = Me.TxtReason.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv9.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 8, 9).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 8, 9).Value = Me.TxtReason.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv10.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 9, 9).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 9, 9).Value = Me.TxtReason.Value
   End If

   ' Copy Registration Date
   .Cells(iRow, 10).Value = Me.TxtDate.Value
   If Me.ListProv2.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 1, 10).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 1, 10).Value = Me.TxtDate.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv3.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 2, 10).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 2, 10).Value = Me.TxtDate.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv4.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 3, 10).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 3, 10).Value = Me.TxtDate.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv5.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 4, 10).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 4, 10).Value = Me.TxtDate.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv6.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 5, 10).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 5, 10).Value = Me.TxtDate.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv7.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 6, 10).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 6, 10).Value = Me.TxtDate.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv8.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 7, 10).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 7, 10).Value = Me.TxtDate.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv9.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 8, 10).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 8, 10).Value = Me.TxtDate.Value
   End If

   If Me.ListProv10.Value = "" Then
   .Cells(iRow + 9, 10).Value = ""
   Else
   .Cells(iRow + 9, 10).Value = Me.TxtDate.Value
   End If

   .Cells(iRow, 11).Value = Me.ListProv1.Value
   .Cells(iRow, 12).Value = Me.ListCity1.Value
   .Cells(iRow + 1, 11).Value = Me.ListProv2.Value
   .Cells(iRow + 1, 12).Value = Me.ListCity2.Value
   .Cells(iRow + 2, 11).Value = Me.ListProv3.Value
   .Cells(iRow + 2, 12).Value = Me.ListCity3.Value
   .Cells(iRow + 3, 11).Value = Me.ListProv4.Value
   .Cells(iRow + 3, 12).Value = Me.ListCity4.Value
   .Cells(iRow + 4, 11).Value = Me.ListProv5.Value
   .Cells(iRow + 4, 12).Value = Me.ListCity5.Value
   .Cells(iRow + 5, 11).Value = Me.ListProv6.Value
   .Cells(iRow + 5, 12).Value = Me.ListCity6.Value
   .Cells(iRow + 6, 11).Value = Me.ListProv7.Value
   .Cells(iRow + 6, 12).Value = Me.ListCity7.Value
   .Cells(iRow + 7, 11).Value = Me.ListProv8.Value
   .Cells(iRow + 7, 12).Value = Me.ListCity8.Value
   .Cells(iRow + 8, 11).Value = Me.ListProv9.Value
   .Cells(iRow + 8, 12).Value = Me.ListCity9.Value
   .Cells(iRow + 9, 11).Value = Me.ListProv10.Value
   .Cells(iRow + 9, 12).Value = Me.ListCity10.Value
   .Protect Password:="Transfer19"

  End With
```

Comment: a picture is worth a thousand words :)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - not sure how to send you a picture in this. Did you want a picture of what my spreadsheet looks like after I run the coding?

Comment: update your question with a picture of your data set up and probably an example of what you want to happen and what is currently happening.

Comment: I would love to do that for you but I have no idea how to either attach a picture or paste a visual of my data set up in the web page

Comment: Check how to add a picture (remember to edit your question) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344851/how-do-you-add-a-screenshot-image-to-your-stack-overflow-post

Comment: Also if you are using windows, check how to take a screenshot https://www.howtogeek.com/226280/how-to-take-screenshots-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

You have a ton of code which can be cut out once you figure out that you can reference the controls on the form in a loop, using their names to get their value

```
Dim n, p, c

For n = 1 to 10
    p = Me.Controls("ListProv" & n).Value
    c = Me.Controls("ListCity" & n).Value
Next n
```

Once you've done that, any changes you need will be 10x easier to make.

**EDIT** - untested but should work

```
Dim info, rw As Range, n As Long

With ws
    'get all the tombstone info into an array
    info = Array(Me.TxtFirst.Value, Me.TxtLast.Value, _
                Me.TxtPRI.Value, Me.TxtGR.Value, _
                Me.TxtLV.Value, Me.TxtLinguistic.Value, _
                Me.TxtEmail.Value, Me.TxtResumeNum.Value, _
                Me.TxtReason.Value, Me.TxtDate.Value)

    .Unprotect Password:="Transfer19"

    'get the first empty row...
    Set rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow

    'loop over the province and city controls
    For n = 1 To 10
         'get province and city values
         p = Me.Controls("ListProv" & n).Value
         c = Me.Controls("ListCity" & n).Value

        If n = 1 Or p <> "" Then                   '<<if on first loop, or province has been selected
            rw.Cells(1).Resize(1, 10).Value = info '<< populate all common info
            rw.Cells(11).Value = p
            rw.Cells(12).Value = c
            Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0) 'move down one row
        End If
    Next n

    .Protect Password:="Transfer19"

End With
```

Comment: @Tim.....thank you but you have me at a lost. What does the coding you just posted allow me to do and what does it replace in my present coding?

Comment: it worked but my previous coding (not shown above) would search for duplicates and if so, it would remove the old info and replace with the new, Can you tell me how to modify my coding so that it does that again -  'searching for duplicates
    Set r = ws.Range("C:C").Find(Me.TxtPRI.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "You already have a record in the National Transfer Inventory. The previous record will be deleted and the new data entered in its place"
        iRow = r.Row
    End If

Comment: If you have a new requirement, please post that as a new question.